# How to select the highest-ancestor element that matches a CSS selector?

Tags: css

Without knowing what the container elements are, how would I write a CSS selector to select only the "root-most" such element(s), without using references to any elements above that?  In other words, suppose I have

```
<...>
  <div class="foo">
    foo1
    <div class="foo">foo2</div>
    <span class="foo">foo3</div>
    <div class="bar">
      bar
      <div class="foo">foo4</div>
    </div>
  <div>
</...>
```

How can I write a CSS selector that only selects the outermost foo and not any of the others inside it?

Intuitively I tried to do `.foo:root` but :root doesn't work like that. Neither will `.foo:first-child` or `.foo:first-of-type` work, as I can't select purely from children of any given element. What else could I do?

Comment: It's not precisely the same, but I believe the top answer on this question will be useful background. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class

Comment: FYI, I asked this here for the pure CSS question, but this question was prompted by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77915667/in-blazor-isolated-css-how-does-one-select-the-root-elements-without-using-a

Answer (score 1):

You select all `.foo`s that don't also match `.foo .foo`.

```css
.foo:not(.foo .foo) {
  border: 2px solid gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  foo1
  <div class="foo">foo2</div>
  <div class="foo">foo3</div>
  <div class="bar">
    bar
    <div class="foo">foo4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit:
Answering the comment, not repeating a selector because of a DRY rule shouldn't be a priority. However, by using a nesting selector one could think of doing something like this:

```css
.foo {
  &:not(& &) {
    border: 2px solid gold;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  foo1
  <div class="foo">foo2</div>
  <div class="foo">foo3</div>
  <div class="bar">
    bar
    <div class="foo">foo4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can check for browser support for CSS nesting on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/css-nesting).
Currently (January 2024) the browser support is rather limited (No safari 16, No Samsung Internet).

Comment: Yep, that would work.  Can you think of any way to do so without repeating the reference to `.foo`, in the interest of DRY?

Comment: Please copy the snippet down here and demonstrate your solution.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski, you don't need to repeat anything. `.foo` and `.foo .foo` are different selectors, and the latter covers any level of nesting.