# In Blazor isolated CSS, how does one select the root element(s) without using a class?

Tags: css, blazor

Suppose I have Foo.razor...

```
<div class="foo">
   <div>Hello</div>
   <div>World</div>
</div>
<span class="foo2">
   Second root element
</span>
```

Is there a CSS selector to put into Foo.razor.css that would select both the root elements of that component but none of their children?  Seems like a very common pattern; it would be nice not to have to.

I tried `*`, `:first-child`, `:first-of-type`, and `:root`, but both by reasoning about it and trying it out, none of these are what I need.

(Under the hood, Blazor applies the generated hash as an attribute; e.g. if I use `*`, it does something like `*[b-qwj487ok39]` which isn't what I want (too broad). [One way would be to end up with the necessary `:not()`:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77915534/7453) `*[b-qwj487ok39]:not([b-qwj487ok39] [b-qwj487ok39])` but there's no way to do that.)

Answer (score 1):

"root element" is not really a thing here. The browser will see the component deeply embedded in the layout and page.

You can make your own root:

```html
<div class="root">
    <div class="foo">
        <div>Hello</div>
        <div>World</div>
    </div>
    <span class="foo2">
        Second root element
    </span>
</div>
```

and then apply a style to the 'root level' elements with

```css
.root > * {
    margin: 1em;
    ...
}
```

The [child combinator (>)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) makes that it only applies to the direct children of a .root element. With the descendant combinator (just a space) the style aplies to all descendants.

Comment: If that's the only way, then you just give every component's root element a class name, likely following the convention that it matches the component name.  I wonder if there is a way where you don't need it.

Comment: Well, this way you only need it once. As I said, there is no other "root level" here.

Comment: Right--that is why I asked this one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77915434/how-to-select-the-highest-ancestor-element-that-matches-a-css-selector/77915534#77915534 :)